# I am getting " ; expected " error i don't know where i miss this sign . who to resolve this issue .code is attached

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing an Asp.net code to play the videos on the website after fetching it from the database. the code is giving error " ; expected " I tried to find where I am missing it but I can't . please help me to resolve it.it is giving error in 8th line i.e.`string text = "<embed src="" + Str + "" height="300" width="500" />";`  here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string play = Request.QueryString["id"];
    string strSQL = "select * from videos where videosong_loc='" + play + "'";

    SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Khawaja\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TaskDB;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlCommand scomm = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sconn);
    sconn.Open();
    SqlDataReader sreader = scomm.ExecuteReader();
    if (sreader.Read())
    {
        string Str = "videos\\" + sreader[1].ToString();
        string text = "<embed src="" + Str + "" height="300" width="500" />";
        //string text = "<embed   height="300" />";
        //Response.Write(text);
        Label1.Text = text;
        sreader.Close();
        sconn.Close();
    }             
}
```

Comment: `string text`  => Escape the `"` within it with `\"`

Comment: Oh dear. Now all I want to do is to visit your site with the following url `http://yoursite.com/yourpage?id='%3Bdrop%20table%20videos%3B` and watch your database quietly drop all your data. **Please act to remove your vulnerability to SQL injection.**

Comment: Care for spenders comment and deal with injection vulnerability,its a pretty old trick but it can get you rekt when you feel everything is going according to plan! Been there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```
 string text = "<embed src="" + Str + "" height="300" width="500" />";
```

You're not escaping your double quotes:

```
string text = "<embed src=\"" + Str + "\" height=\"300\" width=\"500\" />";
```